# Fail to boot after downgrading from ubuntu 15.10 to 14.04lts

Tags: 14.04, boot, 15.04, downgrade

I can see only "Reboot and select proper device" on laptop startup.
Here is my partition configs http://paste.ubuntu.com/10963438/
My laptop model is asus x553m.
I need your help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if your BIOS boot order includes your /dev/sda disk?

If it does, you may try to fix GRUB bootloader using a live cd. The easiest way is using [Super Grub2 or Rescatux](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/).

Advanced users would go with SystemRescueCD following this guide: http://www.sysresccd.org/Sysresccd-Partitioning-EN-Repairing-a-damaged-Grub

Comment: How can I check it?

Comment: When you power on your computer, press specific key to enter BIOS setup. Usually F2, Del, F10 or F12.

Comment: Step by step procedure can be found here (http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ss/bootorderchange.htm) and here (http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/change-boot-order-xp-vista/)